# How do I paste images programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, emoji, custom-keyboard

Is there any way to programatically paste emoji stickers stored in UICollectionView to the text field when tapped?

Here's a link to project for more context: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mohgi/id1080153722?mt=8

Comment: In the link that's been given in the question, I see stickers in the screenshots of the app. If you want to add the stickers programatically, I'd recommend not to add it to the textfield, instead directly create the message cell (I guess it's a subclass of UICollectionViewCell) and add the stickers to it and directly send to the other user when tapped. i.e. whenever user taps on sticker, he will directly be sending the stickers to the other user.

Comment: If you still want to continue with textfield, I guess the only way to do is making your own `Keyboard Extension`.

Comment: Thanks @iamyogish, I will try that! Is there anyway we could chat more on Skype? Can you DM me here?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Thanks.. I've already made my own Keyboard Extension but looking to get stickers to show up in text field immediately after being tapped in the keyboard. Do you have experience with Keyboard extensions?